# Mongo query in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, mongodb

Please help me to get the below complex mongo query using mongoTemplate in spring

i would like to retrieve the collection only if "NAME": "UserID1"?

```
{
    "_id": "12345",
    "A": [{
        "B1": {
            "NAME": "test1",
            "C1": [{
                "D1": [{
                        "NAME": "UserID1"
                    },
                    {
                        "NAME": "UserID2"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "B2": {
            "NAME": "test2",
            "C2": [{
                "D2": [{
                        "NAME": "UserID3"
                    },
                    {
                        "NAME": "UserID4"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for example if assume your class  like this:

```
@Document
public class FirstClass{
  @Id
  String id;
  List<SecondClass> A;

  public class SecondClass{
     string Name;
     List<ThirdClass> C1;

  }
}
```

in mongoTemplate:

```
...
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
...

@Component
    public ServiceClass{
           private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

           ServiceClass(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
                this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
           }

           public List<FirstClass> getResult(String searchInput){
                final Criteria criteria =
                    Criteria.where("A.name").is(searchInput);
                List<FirstClass> result = mongoTemplate.find(new Query(criteria),FirstClass.class);
           }
    }
```

and you can use spring data mongo query like this:

```
public interface FirstClassRepository extends MongoRepository<FirstClass, String> {
        List<FirstClass> findByA_Name(String name);
}
```